# SignalR: Accessing context.ConnectionId outside the context

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have this code

```
public async void Update(Order order, string notes, List<OrderMenu> oMenu, long userId)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PostHub>();
        await hubContext.Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userId.ToString());}
```

I call this method from server via creating object of hub like this

```
ROS.PostHub po = new ROS.PostHub();
            try
            {
                po.Update(new ROS.Order()
```

but context.ConnectionId returns null.

Comment: You should probably be using `async Task` instead of `async void`.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, I also tried `async Task` with no luck.